# Calendar Resource Name change not showing on Subscriptions to the Resource

Tags: android, calendar, google-calendar-api, google-admin-sdk

We've create a New Resource in the Admin Panel of a Google Domain, and we subscribed to that resource using Google Calendar. We then edited the Resource's name in the Admin Panel. We then went back to the Calendar to check if the Subscription to the Resource has changed its name. It doesn't.

If you refresh the browser, you can notice the name shows the newly edited name for a split second, but then gets consumed by the old name.

We've looked at the Android Calendar app and it is exhibiting the same behavior (barring the split-second new name glitch).

Any suggestions or help would be appreciated. I've submitted a ticket to Google through our company, and will hopefully get a reply. If we do get a satisfactory reply, I'll update this post.

Also, I've posted on Google's Support Forum here:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/calendar/report-an-issue/user-interface-and-views/desktop---other/RgtvnH4cXUE
Consider starring the issue if you can replicate this behavior.

Thanks!
Andrew Fleming

Answer (score 0):

Update: I spoke with Google through a support ticket where I work, and they say they can reproduce this issue (including the split second where the subscription name is updated). They said that the common thought is that it will take 24 hours to update the Calendar Sub. I'll be keeping an eye on this and if I get anymore information, I'll report back here.